# Ubuntu makes my computer clear and blank

Tags: logs

Today I got the second time a similar problem with my Ubuntu.
The first time it was in September, the second one is today.
For the first time, it was updated by itself to the new Ubuntu version and deletes all my files. So, I was working and then find myself, that I didn't see some folders. I restart the notebook and see the completely new OS, new version and without my files. It was a lot of free space, so all my files were deleted. And I didn't solve that problem. I have lost all my data. That time I thought, I have allowed installing a new version of Ubuntu, but I didn't do this.

Yesterday I start to work on my notebook (the OS was reinstalled by me on another HDD), run the IntellijIdea, see the project and start to work. Then I see, the folder "Documents" marked by grey and I cannot enter it. Then I see, that the project files in IntellijIdea are file by file are dissapearing and the project is completely new, as it was just created. Then I switched off the notebook and connect this HDD to another Ubuntu computer - It cannot be viewed. I connect it to Win10 computer - it cannot be viewed. I connect to Mint computer and I see, that the folder "Documents" exists, but it has an only blank project for IntellijIdea. So, no any my folders or files. But I found a folder without a name and enter it - it was my old "Documents". So, I gave the name for it and copied all my needed files to separate HDD. I was lucky this time.

Can you please help me - what is this? How it is possible, what to do for not having this in the future? I have a different types of log files. Which ones can help to understand, what was the problem?

**Additional information:**
1. The file /etc/fstab:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

2. The result of lsblk | grep -v loop:

```
punisher@punisher-HP:~$ lsblk | grep -v loop
NAME                  MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda                     8:0    0 298,1G  0 disk 
└─sda1                  8:1    0 298,1G  0 part 
  ├─ubuntu--vg-root   253:0    0 297,1G  0 lvm  /
  └─ubuntu--vg-swap_1 253:1    0   980M  0 lvm  [SWAP]
```

Comment: Were the deleted files in your /home directory? Or someplace else?

Comment: Yes, there were in my home directory. But the folder was without name.

Comment: Ubuntu will **never** automatically delete user data upon updating. So what you describe appears highly unlikely, unless you have a severe hardware issue with the disk containing the data (which I understand may be a separate disk that the system). Provide info on how drives are connected (cat /etc/fstab, lsblk | grep -v loop)

Comment: Dear vanadium, I have added the information from file /etc/fstab to the initial text. The command you wrote I cannot enter, because I am afraid to start ubuntu from that HDD. In my system I have just one HDD, and another one was external and connected via USB. No CDrom etc.

Comment: Is this system encryped? Or merely LVM?

Comment: No encryption. I did not additional volumes, just one system to just full HDD.

Comment: Dear vanadium, I have added the result of "lsblk | grep -v loop" command. I put the HDD back to notebook and it works as needed, of course with a renamed "Documents". Others folders exists and the software works well. How to understand what it was? Is it possible via logs?